# How to create pg_dump using pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, shell

I have pgAdmin III ver 9.4 and I'm trying to create pg_dump using SQL Shell (psql) but does not seems to work, is there  away you can create dump using pgAdmin ?

this is what I have done so far using SQL Shell
1) fire up the Shell
2) Server [localhost] - after hit enter I see
3) Database [postgres] - type > `pg_dump test_db | gzip > test_db_backup.gz`
4) next I see nothing nothing no response

I shown in the screen shot
[image]

Answer (score 2):

pg_dump is a compiled utility program. Exit the psql shell, and run pg_dump from a bash (or whatever) shell prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Backup option available when you right click the database. Select 'Plain" format if you just want the SQL commands in text format.